# How to read a image from isolated-storage and display it on Image element?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need to load an image from [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), and display it on an Image UIElement.
I have surveyed MSDN, and I found I cannot get an Uri from IsolatedStorage. I could get a stream for the saved jpeg image file.

After I get the jpeg file stream, how do I show it on an Image element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use BitmapImage.SetSource to read the stream and then set the Image.Source to the BitmapImage:

```
Stream jpegStream;
var image1 = new BitmapImage();
image1.SetSource(jpegStream);
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = image1;
```